# HTTP Response Headers (cache clearing) across an entire solution

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, caching

I have a solution with a large pile of aspx pages. We also work in an environment where CSS/js files change relatively regularly (far more often than my dev team and I would prefer). This presents a problem to our users when we make these CSS/js changes, in that our users end up with cache conflicts. We generally will direct them to clear their cache and it solves everything, but we'd just as soon not have to tell them to clear their cache.

So I employed HTML Response Headers from a post I saw here in order to get users to clear their caches:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

This seems to be working alright. I also thought about using the querystring parameter on our js files to force the refresh:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which will likely help our js/css caching issues, but I'm not convinced that's the only page content being cached (and thereby throwing errors during a major release).

Once I'm convinced that using the HTML Response Headers is accomplishing its goal I plan to apply an expiry as well.

So the question is: do I have to add this (being the Response headers) to every single aspx in our solution? Can I just load it into the Parent frame and have the child iframes "inherit" that cache-clearing? If not that, can I put it into a Master page and have the content pages receive those headers from the Master page? Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a master page then setting the headers in there will be sufficient.

More widely speaking, here's how we handle this scenario:

1. We use Cruise Control to generate a text file containing a release
   id for each build (eg "2014-05-13.001")
2. In .net we use a StreamReader to grab the current buildId and store
   it in the Application object
3. We append the id as a querystring parameter to all our CSS and JS file references.

This way, whenever we release a version, all CSS and JS files are cleared and reloaded.  The downside is that *all* files are cleared, not just those that have been modified, but we don't make many public releases, and it's better than the alternative.

Comment: I'm implementing the js/css idea in the fashion of

'<script src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?rndstr=<%= getRandomStr() %>" type="text/javascript"></script>'

with the c# function

'    protected string getRandomStr()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rando = r.Next();
        return rando.ToString();
    }'

As far as I know this works in master pages.

I'm more concerned about the individual aspx pages. I just learned Masters don't have Page_PreInit, so that's a snag for the c# side. I'll start with the JS/CSS version implementation and go from there.

Comment: The disadvantage of the random number approach is that the files will *never* be cached, which is less than ideal and is going to slow down every page load.